# Reference of a Paper on Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I was searching a paper of Tuan H. F. on "A Theorem about $p$-groups with abelian subgroup of index $p$". It is published in *Acad. Sinica Science Record, 3(1950), 17-23*.

I tried to get a copy of this paper, but I couldn't find through internet. Only one place, I found a link to this paper ([see this](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/vol_43/no1_07.html)). But again, there is a problem to access this paper.

It will be great pleasure for me if one can show a link to the paper or at least the main theorem(s) in the paper proved by author.

Comment: I think you will get a paid copy from world scientific.

Comment: Have you tried to contact [Academia Sinica](http://www.sinica.edu.tw/main_e.shtml)?

Comment: The [link you found](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0041135) is not a link to a paper but to [Mathematical Reviews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Reviews); where a short review is given. I am not sure whether it can be reproduced here - [for copyright reasons](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/fair-use-mathscinet). You could also try to get the article via [interlibrary loan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlibrary_loan) at your nearest library.

Comment: You can easily find via [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16506866570385641232&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) (or some other database) the papers citing this one. If you have access to some of them, maybe the results of that paper are paraphrased there.

Answer (score 4):

I transcribe here the results from the said paper in which main theorem states (with the proof omitted):

> **Theorem.** If a nonabelian $p$-group $\mathfrak{G}$ of order $p^n$ contains an abelian
>   subgroup $\mathfrak{A}$ of order $p^{n - 1}$ and if $\mathfrak{Z}$
>   and $\mathfrak{K}$ denote respectively the centrum and the commutator subgroup
>   of $\mathfrak{G}$, then
>   $$\mathfrak{A}/\mathfrak{Z} \cong \mathfrak{K}$$
>   and $\mathfrak{Z} \cap \mathfrak{K}$ is abelian of type $\left( p, p,
> \cdots, p \right)$. Whence, denoting by $p^z$ and $p^k$ the orders
>   of $\mathfrak{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{K}$ respectively, we have
>   $$n = k + z + 1.$$

More generally:

> **Theorem'.** If a $p$-group $\mathfrak{G}$ of order $p^n$ contains a maximal normal abelian subgroup $\mathfrak{A}$ with cyclic factor group $\mathfrak{G}/\mathfrak{A}$, and if  $\mathfrak{Z}$
>   and $\mathfrak{K}$ denote respectively the centrum and the commutator subgroup
>   of $\mathfrak{G}$, we have
>   $$\mathfrak{A}/\mathfrak{Z}\cong\mathfrak{K}.$$
>   Furthermore if $p^z$, $p^k$ and $p^d$ denote the orders of $\mathfrak{Z}$, $\mathfrak{K}$ and $\mathfrak{G}/\mathfrak{A}$ respectively, then all the elements of $\mathfrak{Z} \cap \mathfrak{K}$ have their orders not exceeding $p^d$, and
>   $$n=k+z+d.$$

The extension:

> **Extension.** Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be a $p$-group of order $p^n$. Let its class be $c$, its lower central series be
>   $$\mathfrak{G}=\mathfrak{G}_1 \supset \mathfrak{K} = \mathfrak{G}_2 = (\mathfrak{G},\mathfrak{G})\supset \cdots \supset \mathfrak{G}_c \supset \mathfrak{G}_{c+1} =I.$$
>   and its upper central series be
>   $$\mathfrak{G}=\mathfrak{Z}_c\supset \mathfrak{Z}_{c-1} \supset \cdots \supset \mathfrak{Z}_1 = \mathfrak{Z} \supset \mathfrak{Z}_0=I.$$
>   Let $\mathfrak{G}$ contain an abelian subgroup $\mathfrak{A}$ of order $p^{n-1}$, then we have
>   $$\mathfrak{A}/\mathfrak{A}\cap\mathfrak{Z}_i\cong\mathfrak{G}_{i+1},\quad i=1,\cdots,c.$$
>   In fact, for $i=1,\cdots,c-1$, $\mathfrak{A}$ must contain $\mathfrak{Z}_i$, and hence
>   $$\mathfrak{A}/\mathfrak{Z}_i\cong\mathfrak{G}_{i+1},\quad i=1,\cdots,c-1.$$
>   If we denote by $p^{z_i}$ and $p^{k_{i+1}}$ the orders of $\mathfrak{Z}_i$ and $\mathfrak{G}_{i+1}$, we have
>   $$n=z_i+k_{i+1}+1,\quad i=1,\cdots,c-1.$$

Answer (score 3):

The only reference I have indeed is only via Berkovich's book *"Groups of Prime Power Order, Vol 1"*. I have to write out it as on my bookshelf and not pdf. There we have:

*According to Tuan* if a $p$ group $G$ has a normal abelian subgroup $A$ with cyclic quotient group $G/A$, then $A/(A\cap Z(G))\cong G'$ (see also I.M.Isaacs "Character Theory of finite groups, Acad. Press, N.Y. 1976" Lemma 12.12).

A group $G$ is said *minimal nonabelian* if it is non-abelian but all its proper subgroups are abelian.

[image]